# How are university departments receiving corporate funding?

Tags: funding, university, industry

I learned in class that some departments of universities, such as the medical departments, receive funding from corporation that bypass the university administrators, such that the research finding can be used for the profit of the corporations.

I also read that similar mechanism is influencing the curriculum-design of computer science. I want to know how exactly would a corporation fund the research of a department, computer science in particular.

The following is my baseless conjecture on how the interactions works, even though it's probably nonsense, I think it may help you understand the kind of answer I am looking for:
*A certain corporation wants a new technology for its products, say phones, it asks the administrator of a university whether the latter wants funding for its computer science department. The administrator thinks that if some funding for computer science is handled by the corp., then more fund can be distributed to other things, and so approves this funding. The department uses the funding to do research, but the research is what the corp. asks them to do. When the department found a novel method of making phone computers, but instead of getting a patent, the department gives the patent to the corp. which uses it for its products*

Comment: Are you asking only about funding for a _department_ that comes from industry, or are you also interested in how industry might fund research projects of a particular professor or research group?

Comment: Your suppositions seem indeed to be baseless conjecture, and I'm not quite sure what motivates the fairly negative spin you put on it. Funds in to a university do go through standard university channels. The ability for a company to fund relevant research, and perhaps have some title in it, is pretty standard at all US universities that I have dealt with.

Comment: If the corporations "bypass the university administrators", how is it that in your "baseless conjecture", a corporation "asks the administrator of a university" before doing anything?

Comment: "When the department found a novel method ..." - at least in my perspective from a country where universities are not supposed to produce anything marketable in order to improve their finances, "getting a patent" was never the plan in the first place for "the department". With or without the corporation, the research results are published and can thus be used by everyone around the planet. Beside any funding, the really valuable benefit for "the department" is usually getting access to *real world* test data and *real* users. The benefit for the corporation is knowing about the results ...

Comment: ... a few weeks earlier than anyone else, and probably getting readily prepared prototypes and test results that exactly fit their own specific use cases (because that's what you get when you provide your specific test data and test users), as well as some additional public exposure.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I'm not sure what country you are in but in the US it is common for universities to retain ownership of marketable intellectual property. For example, at UW-Madison, WARF (Wisconsin Alumni Research Foundation) handles patents produced by the university and funds a lot of university research. The drug "warfarin" is, in fact, named after WARF. If a private company contracts with a university, even a public one, the terms of that contract could include full intellectual property rights - most professors would demand to at least have publication rights but may cede any commercial use.

Comment: (I should clarify that WARF is technically an independent entity from the university but they are tightly linked to one another)

Comment: @BryanKrause - Precisely - most universities (Cornell, MIT, CalTech, Stanford, ...) have IP experts, usually under the Dean of Research, to apply for relevant patents and ensure that any IP generated under contracts (with companies or the government) is handled correctly. In the US at least, to think that companies are coming in some backdoor is strange to say the least. (Often there is also funding available to spin out companies based on such IP).

Comment: @BryanKrause: Over here in Germany, at least in CS, the statement "We only create prototypes, no marketable products." is a very frequently heard sentence. If someone does indeed create something marketable that they want to sell, they will be supported by the university's start-up support programmes to found a new company that will then sell the product. I have even been part of a project once where the greatest concern of the project leads was that our prototypes "look too professional" and someone might mistake them for real products and accuse us of violating the project guidelines.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I think that makes sense, and the situation in the US is similar in most cases - in the WARF example I gave, the university is not producing a product directly, but they are managing intellectual property to the benefit of research at the university. There are also many start-up companies that have used intellectual property initially created in the university and have employees who are also university faculty.

Comment: @JonCuster I wouldn't describe it as a "back door" but companies in the US definitely fund research projects at universities directly, and then benefit from the proceeds. This is usually not too controversial, but there are some exceptions, such as when companies use their sway to influence projects they don't fund ("If you publish X we will stop funding Y") or prevent publication on projects they initially agreed for publication on. In engineering, for example, it is common for a company to fund a student to do PhD/masters work at a university that directly benefits the company.

Comment: Some universities are no longer filing patents because they were losing money.  They were costing more to administer than they brought in from licence fees.